# scikit-image save image to a bytestring

Tags: python, in-memory, stringio, scikit-image

I'm using [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) to read an image:

```
img = skimage.io.imread(filename)
```

After doing some manipulations to `img`, I'd like to save it to an in-memory file (a la [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html)) to pass off to another function, but it looks like [`skimage.io.imsave`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#imsave) requires a filename, not a file handle.

I'd like to avoid hitting the disk (`imsave` followed by read from another imaging library) if at all possible. Is there a nice way to get `imsave` (or some other scikit-image-friendly function) to work with `StringIO`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update: 2020-05-07**

We now recommend using the `imageio` library for image reading and writing.  Also, with Python 3, StringIO changes to BytesIO:

```
from io import BytesIO
import imageio

buf = BytesIO()
imageio.imwrite(buf, image, format='png')
```

---

`scikit-image` stores images as numpy arrays, therefore you can use a package such as `matplotlib` to do so:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from StringIO import StringIO

s = StringIO()

plt.imsave(s, img)
```

This may be worth adding as default behaviour to `skimage.io.imsave`, so if you want you can also file an issue at https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan! I created the issue here: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/533

Comment: Is this still the state of affairs as of 2020?