# concatenate two images from plt.imsave with different cmaps without installing another package

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm making movies by saving a series of images, then using [ImageJ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/) to put them together, as so:

```
for i in range(n):
    fname = 'out_' + str(1000+i)
    plt.imsave(fname, A[i], cmap=cmapA)
```

I'd like to somehow "concatenate" two images (so they appear side-by-side for example) and save, produced with different colormaps. So hypothetically:

```
for i in range(n):
    fname = 'out_' + str(1000+i)
    plt.hypothetical_imsave(fname,  (A[i], B[i]),  cmap=(cmapA, cmapB),  axis=1)
```

Of course, this is pseudocode, but is there some way to do this with good old numpy and matplotlib without installing a whole new package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating the two interim images like my answer above, an alternative way is to make the two arrays using `imshow`, like in the example below.

We will grab the numpy array from the `imshow` object using `._rgbacache`, but to generate this you have to display the `imshow` object on an axis, hence the `fig` and `ax` at the beginning.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Need to display the result of imshow on an axis
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

# Save fig a with one cmap
a=np.random.rand(20,20)
figa=ax.imshow(a,cmap='jet')

# Save fig b with a different cmap
b=np.random.rand(20,20)
figb=ax.imshow(a,cmap='copper')

# Have to show the figure to generate the rgbacache
fig.show()

# Get the array of data
figa=figa._rgbacache
figb=figb._rgbacache

# Stitch the two arrays together
figc=np.concatenate((figa,figb),axis=1)

# Save without a cmap, to preserve the ones you saved earlier
plt.imsave('figc.png',figc,cmap=None)
```

**EDIT:**

To do this with `imsave` and a file-like object, you need `cStringIO`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cStringIO import StringIO

s=StringIO()
t=StringIO()

# Save fig a with one cmap to a StringIO instance. Need to explicitly define format
a=np.random.rand(20,20)
plt.imsave(s,a,cmap='jet',format='png')

# Save fig b with a different cmap
b=np.random.rand(20,20)
plt.imsave(t,b,cmap='copper',format='png')

# Return to beginning of string buffer
s.seek(0)
t.seek(0)

# Get the array of data
figa=plt.imread(s)
figb=plt.imread(t)

# Stitch the two arrays together
figc=np.concatenate((figa,figb),axis=1)

# Save without a cmap, to preserve the ones you saved earlier
plt.imsave('figc.png',figc,cmap=None)
```

Comment: Interesting! This is another solution! Though it's not ideal either, it is very handy if I don't want to deal with so much I/O to the hard drive. Thanks!  (but I still wonder if there is a way using the "file-like object" instead of actually writing to the hard drive).

Comment: Ah right, I think I understand now. Maybe you need something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16165168/588071

Comment: @uhoh Just added how to do this above

Comment: don't think cStringIO should need any installation, but if you're happy, I'm happy!

Comment: EDITED COMMENT: Oh, I see! Thanks @tom, now you have three distinct solutions! I'm a happy camper. Next frontier:  manually generate the image (rgb-alpha) with the cmap and skip all the higher level methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `imsave` to save both images with the desired `cmap`s first, then reopen them with `imread`, `concatenate` the arrays, and then use `imsave` again to save the concatenated figure with `cmap` set to `None`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Save fig a with one cmap
a=np.random.rand(200,200)
plt.imsave('figa.png',a,cmap='jet')

# Save fig b with a different cmap
b=np.random.rand(200,200)
plt.imsave('figb.png',a,cmap='copper')

# Reopen fig a and fig b
figa=plt.imread('figa.png')
figb=plt.imread('figb.png')

# Stitch the two figures together
figc=np.concatenate((figa,figb),axis=1)

# Save without a cmap, to preserve the ones you saved earlier
plt.imsave('figc.png',figc,cmap=None)
```

Figure a, with `jet` cmap

[image: figa]

Figure b, with `copper` cmap

[image: figb]

Figure c

[image: figc]

Comment: Sweet!  Thanks @tom, it works!  But now this has me thinking about how to avoid the hard drive. `help(plt.imsave)` says a "file-like object" can be used instead of a filename.

Comment: There is a way, using imshow instead of imsave. I'll make a new answer with the alternate method